# What's the difference between 1024 and 1024L while assigning variable?

Tags: c

What's the difference ? Both of them give same output while using printf("%ld")

```c
long x = 1024;
long y = 1024L;
```

Comment: `1024` is an integer literal. `1024L` is a long integer literal, you'll find you need to add the `L` if you have integer literals bigger than what a normal integer is able to hold.

Comment: It changes the type of the literal value. `1024` is an `int`, `1024` is a `long int`. The effect is the same because assigning an `int` to a `long` follows integer promotion rules.

Comment: Thanks guys, but why when I use long x while assigning it's still int, if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C source code, `1024` is an `int`, and `1024L` is a `long int`. During an assignment, the value on the right is converted to the type of the left operand. As long as the rules about which combinations of operands are obeyed and the value on the right is in the range of the left operand, there is no difference—the value remains unchanged.

In general, a decimal constant without a suffix is an `int`, and a decimal constant with an `L` is a `long int`. However, if its value is too big to be represented in the usual type, it will automatically be the next larger type. For example, in a C implementation where the maximum `int` is 2147483647, the constant `3000000000` in source code will be a `long int` even though it has no suffix. (Note that this rule means the same constant in source code can have different types in different C implementations.) If a `long int` is not big enough, it will be `long long int`. If that is not big enough, it can be a signed extended integer type, if the implementation supports one.

The rules above are for decimal constants. There are also hexadecimal constants (which begin with `0x` or `0X`) and octal constants (which begin with `0`—`020` is octal for sixteen, unlike `20` which is decimal for twenty), which may have signed or unsigned types. The different integer types are important because overflow and conversions behave differently depending on type. It is easy to take integer operations as a matter of course and assume they work, but it important to learn the details to avoid problems.